# Menu different wrap for previous and next item

Tags: menu, typo3

I am trying myself on a progress bar kind of menu in TYPO3 and have come up with the following menu. So far so good:

```
   1 = TMENU
        1 {
          noBlur = 1
          wrap = <ul class="crumbs-bar">|</ul>
          expAll = 1
          NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="visited first">|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li>|</li>
          ACT=1
          ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="visited first">|</li> |*| <li class="active">|</li> |*| <li>|</li>
        }
      }
```

No what I need to add is a wrap for the previous and the next menu item (`<li class="previous">` and `<li class="next">`) to make it work. I have found several examples of prev/next menus for TYPO3 but seem unable to integrate it into my code.

It is supposed to look something like this (assuming Item 4 is active):

- Item 1 | `class="first visited"`
- Item 2
- Item 3 | `class="previous visited"`
- Item 4 | `class="active"`
- Item 5 | `class="next"`
- Item 6
- Item 7

And so forth...

Comment: I have meanwhile experimented with optionSplit but did not get where I wanted? Maybe that is a lead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to write a little bit of code yourself. Take a look on the `itemArrayProcFunc` or `IProcFunc` property of the [tmenu](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Tmenu/Index.html). You can find some example code in [this blog post](http://www.adick.at/2014/02/02/typo3-extension-records-innerhalb-eines-typoscript-menues-ausgeben/) or in the [statictemplates extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/statictemplates) of TYPO3 of how to use this feature, it is in German though.